# Rails3 - Create A Static Web Page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create static web pages in my App - T&Cs, About, Privacy etc... I could just create blank pages and put them in the public folder and put 'href' links to them. Is this considered best practice? or should I use rails g controller for each of them? What's the difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oftentimes I will make a `site` controller that has actions for each of the public pages, assuming there isn't going to be a ton of content on the public side. If there was more, I would look into some kind of CMS. Anyway, create a `site` controller, and then create routes and templates for each of the pages you need. That way you'll be able to use a layout, and use Rails helpers if you need them.

Answer (score 8):

HighVoltage is a gem that helps out with exactly what you're taking about:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

It makes it really easy to handle these scenarios.  From the docs:

Write your static pages and put them in the RAILS_ROOT/app/views/pages directory.

```
$ mkdir app/views/pages
$ touch app/views/pages/about.html.erb
```

After putting something interesting there, you can link to it from anywhere in your app with:

```
link_to "About", page_path("about")
```

This will also work, if you like the more explicit style:

```
link_to "About", page_path(:id => "about")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can just create `about.html`, etc and put them into the `public` folder.  If it's just a completely static web page, then the controller adds no value.  Subdirectories also work just fine in the `public` folder, as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using this awesome GEM https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

Answer (score 1):

Just dawned me that this should actually be quite easy, hopefully, think this through:

**Create a route like for example:**

```
match '/about' => "static#about"
```

**~ then create a simple controller, in this case app/controllers/static_controller.rb**

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  def about
    # nuttin
  end
end
```

**~ now all we need is a view: ( /app/views/static/about.html.erb )**

```
Hey!
```

**Sorted**

Comment: forgot I wrote this and came here to help myself :]

Answer (score 1):

Create static page 'home'

```
$ rails generate controller Pages home
```

A new controller 'pages' is added with action 'home'. A new route is inserted into 'config/routes.rb'

```
# config/routes.rb
get "pages/home"
```

To generate a link to page 'Home'

```
<%= link_to "Home", :controller => "pages", :action => "home" %>
```